# How to connect my electric Ikea cooking plate?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, installation

My old cooktop broke so I am currently trying to install a new electric ceramic hob ([Ikea Barmhartig](http://www.ikea.com/be/fr/catalog/products/10222821/)).

How can I make the proper connections? The back panel looks like this:

[image: electric circuit cover at the back]

[image: label at the back]

How do I open the circuit cover without breaking it, and then attach the wires? The wires look like this (I know the L1 L2 Neutral and Earth):

[image: wires to connect]

previous configuration: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first picture shows a diagram on the junction box, where two screwdrivers are prying in certain spots to get it open.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could get it open. Can you also help me  with the wiring please?Looks like there are two ways to wire this system. Since I have five wires (3 phase) I want to use the 400 V 2L-1N configuration. The Yellow/Green one is Ground(PE) and the Blue is Neutral. I need to identify which ones are L1 , L2 and L3. Brown one should be L1 according to convention, then I have two wires left, one is black and the other one is also black with "Siemens VDE" printed on it. Can any one of these be used as L2 for connection? PLease advise.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: What country are you in?

In the first image along the top of that terminal block you can clearly read "*earth*-N-3-2-1".
The second image shows the wiring diagram of how to connect to these quick-wire terminal holes. 
Blue = Neutral
Brown = Live
Green/Yel = Earth

Unfortunately I have no idea what the two black wires are. What is on the other end of that cord?

Comment: I am in Luxembourg. The other end of the wire is connected to the wall ( wiring sustem) . I might have a clue though. My previous cooktop was connected to the wires... let me post a picture

Comment: pic uploaded. YOu can see the cut wires at the bottom. THe black with white print is at the top.